# Find $\frac{x^2}{y} + \frac{y^2}{z} + \frac{z^2}{x} \to \min$

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I'm trying to solve
\begin{align*}
&\frac{x^2}{y} + \frac{y^2}{z} + \frac{z^2}{x} \to \min \\
&x + y + z = 1 \\
&x, y, z > 0,
\end{align*}
using only inequalities.
How can i solve it? I used am-gm, tried to "break" terms, but got only after all $(xy + yz + xz) = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Suppose wlog $x\le y\le z\Rightarrow \frac1x\ge \frac1y\ge \frac1z$. If $a_1<a_2<a_3$ the minimum $(a_1,a_2,a_3).(b_{\sigma(1)},b_{\sigma(2)},b_{\sigma(3)})$ over all $\sigma$ is achieved when $b_{\sigma(1)}>b_{\sigma(2)}>b_{\sigma(3)}$ it's a famous named result but I've forgotten the name... so $\frac{x^2}{y}+\frac{y^2}{z}+\frac{z^2}{x}\ge\frac{x^2}{x}+\frac{y^2}{y}+\frac{z^2}{z}=x+y+z=1$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin this famous named result is called is the Rearrangement Inequality.  I didn't read your comment but had posted as much.

Comment: Just think a little bit before posting

Comment: @SohamChatterjee well, if you insist on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$\sum\dfrac{x^2}{y}\sum y\geq(x+y+z)^2$$
or an even simpler one is:
$$\sum\dfrac{x^2}{y}-\sum y = \sum\left(\dfrac{x^2}{y} - 2x+y\right)=\sum\dfrac{(x-y)^2}{y}\geq 0.$$

Answer (score -1):

By Cauchy-Schwarz we get$$\frac{x^2}{y} + \frac{y^2}{z} + \frac{z^2}{x} \geq \frac{(x+y+z)^2}{x+y+z}=1$$

Comment: why have you posted the answer, if we already have one? Note that it's using Cauchy-Schwarz also

Comment: I am using cauchy scwarz but with a different apporach

Comment: But why? Nevermind, then, please, make your 'different approach' obvious.